# get height of element by class name with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, height

```js
var height = $("#my").height();
console.log(height);


var height = $(".mymy").get(0).height(); 
console.log(height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='my'>this is some text</div>


<div class='mymy'>class text 1</div>
<div class='mymy'>class <br> text<br> 2</div>
```

I can get the height when I have an id but is it possible to get the height by class name?  Consider:

```
<div id='my'>this is some text</div>

var height = $("#my").height();
```

will get me the height of the element. How do you do that when you get elements by class name? consider:

```
<div class='mymy'>class text 1</div>
<div class='mymy'>class <br> text<br> 2</div>

var height = $(".mymy").get(0).height()
```

is not working

Comment: Your console should be telling you that `height()` is not a function

Comment: well yes, but how do you get it?

Comment: "*How do you do that when you get elements by class name?*" that depends on what result you want to get. Do you want to get the height of *all* of the elements with that class-name? Or just one of them? Or some of them? How should we, or your program, know what you want to do; are you passing arguments in some way? Please: tell us the result you want.

Comment: I already posted an answer with the correct method to use.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica err, this isn't a too broad question.  It's fairly straight forward that the issue is the use of `get(0)` breaking the element out of the jQuery object.

Comment: Sure, but until the OP actually explains what s/he wants there is still ambiguity in the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eq(0)` to keep the element in a jQuery object.

Comment: Assuming the OP desires to find the height of the zeroeth object - as you seem to be doing here - there's no need for [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: Bah, typo in the fiddle.  Yeah, that appears to be accurate as well.  It's always a good idea to be explicit though

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica what do you mean there is no need for `eq`?  I'd agree the usage of the 0 in this case is up to developer taste, but are you saying the method is not needed at all?

Comment: Yes, it's not needed at all (on the assumption it's the zeroeth element that's required); any getter method that iterates over a collection of elements will return the result of that method on the first element in the collection.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica In that case I would disagree with you, purely on a self-documentation point of view.  imo, it is always better to write your code in a way that confers intent.  If you leave off the `eq()` all together, it is unclear if you did indeed only want to get the first one, or if it just accidentally worked without you being aware.